# UK Standard Visitor Visa With Prior Travel to Gibraltar

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, deception, gibraltar

An interesting question came up earlier today in an email (uninvited) from a person who travels on an Egyptian passport. She wants to apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).

The form asks as question like "Have you ever visited the UK?", here's a screen shot... 
[image]

The person has not been in England or Wales or Scotland or Northern Ireland, but they have travelled to [Gibraltar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar) recently and have seen that this country is a '[British Overseas Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_Territories)'.  So should they answer 'yes' and fill out the Details Section?

Or alternatively would answering 'no' place them in jeopardy of a refusal for deception?

I suppose the answer would be canonical for all British Overseas Territories unless special conditions applied to Gibraltar. If your answer is canonical to all British Overseas Territories please indicate specifically.

Comment: Is there a section for extra information in the application(most paper applications have so assuming), can't they mention it there and say no in the query ?

Comment: @DumbCoder while that is a practical way about the problem, this question surely deserves an exhaustive answer as it's an interesting one.

Comment: Is "purpose of trip" free-form text? If so, it's hard to see any possible harm from saying that you visited Gibraltar on such and such a date. Either it's the information they're looking for, or it's a small amount of irrelevant extra information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question basically asks whether Gibraltar is part of the UK. From the wiki page that you linked to:

> The 14 British Overseas Territories (BOT) are territories under the jurisdiction and sovereignty of the United Kingdom. They are the parts of the British Empire that have not been granted independence or have voted to remain British territories. **These territories do not form part of the United Kingdom** and, with the exception of Gibraltar, are not part of the European Union.

(emphasis mine)

This means that the truthful answer to the question "Have you ever travelled to the UK in the last 10 years?" is **no**. The same is true for all BOT.

I don't see why truthfully answering a question would be considered deception.

Comment: I realise that the question comes from Gayot, so I am suspicious that it would be this simple. But someone should post the obvious answer.